# mongoDB findone return null

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

was trying to query findone in mongoDB then i try to console.log but it was null
`const pc = await ProductCategories.findOne({categoriesName : kategor)})`
`console.log(pc)`

i was expecting to get 1 collection out of it

```
{
        "_id": "6530d933e2d81516c091de0d",
        "categoriesName": "List",
        "unit": "Biji",
        "__v": 0,
        "unitConversion": ""
}
```

Comment: I would assume a typo in collection name or field name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
{
        "_id": "6530d933e2d81516c091de0d",
        "categoriesName": "List",
        "unit": "Biji",
        "__v": 0,
        "unitConversion": ""
}
```

if this document is in your database you can try it:

```js
const findOneCategory = async ()=>{
    const pc = await ProductCategories.findOne({categoriesName : "List" )})
    console.log(pc)
}
```